# ReactJS listView to React Native ListvIew

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My target is to convert react listView to working react-native ListView. First code is working reactJs code, second is my react-native try. Main issue is that I need replacement for data.map. This will allow me to get url. [reference](http://www.webpackbin.com/VJf-ndMib)

**EDIT**

I don't get an error but ListView fields are empty.

```
class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'BLAH'});
    }


    render(){
       return (<div>
            {this.props.exception && <span>exception: {this.props.exception}</span>}
            Data: {this.props.data.map(e=><div key={e.id}>{e.url}</div>)}

          </div>);
    }
}

export default connect( state =>({
    data:state.data , exception:state.exception
}))(App);
```

to react-native Listview:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super();
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.data)
      };
      console.log(props.data)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.dispatch({type: 'BLAH'});
    }

    renderRow(rowData) {
      return (
        <View>
            <Text>{rowData.url}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }

    render(){
       return (
         <View>
           <ListView dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow}/>
         </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect( state =>({
    data:state.data
}))(App);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need replacement for data.map function in react native, because I cannot set this.props.data

Comment: just replace ['row 1', 'row 2'] with this.props.data

Comment: it is empty. if you debug example in app.js you will see in beginning is empty and just after render it is filled

Comment: could the problem be in export default connect( state =>({
    data:state.data
}))(App);

Comment: react-native code has no errors, but show empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `componentWillReceiveProps` solve the problem:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newProps.data),
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the ListView docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html). The data source property takes an instance of [`ListViewDataSource`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html), not an array of your data.

The docs show a minimal example implementation:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  return {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
  };
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
    />
  );
},
```

Comment: Yes, it is an extract of the docs, demonstrating how a `ListView` needs to be provided with data.

Comment: I cannot access this page from the machine I'm using.